# Collection getSize returns Zero

Tags: magento2, pagination

I am using Magento 2.4.1 with PHP 7.4
I am unable to view paging inside the category view page.
By debugging the code I found that inside
`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar.phtml`

This method `<?php if ($block->getCollection()->getSize()) :?>` not working and returning Zero result.

So I replaced this with `<?php if (count($block->getCollection())) :?>`

Now toolbar is showing like below and showing 0 items
[image]

Also inside  `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar/amount.phtml`

this method  `<?php if ($block->getLastPageNum() > 1) :?>` returns Zero result.

The main issue is paging not showing.

Answer (score 5):

I found what is causing the problem, as described here

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29777

it is an ElasticSearch7/Magento2 issue.

Take a look in `vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch-7/SearchAdapter/Adapter.php`

`public function query(RequestInterface $request) : QueryResponse`

`$rawResponse['hits']['total']['value']`
is not existent sometimes (why so ever).

The total value is found then in `$rawResponse['hits']['total']`

I guess I have to build a plugin (its a public function) and check the value. Something like that

```
if (isset($rawResponse['hits']['total']['value'])) {
    $total = $rawResponse['hits']['total']['value'];
}
elseif (isset($rawResponse['hits']['total'])) {
    $total = $rawResponse['hits']['total'];
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: good to know you got the solution! With the same code base on an unmanaged server, my store is working fine. Showing toolbar and paging also.

Comment: Yes, it helped, thanks for this solution, actually the ES version is - 6.8.3 and Magento version was 2.4.3, and the toolbar block (pagination) was not showing, so further debugged but had no luck and when tried your solution it worked and came to know that ED is outdated.

Comment: yes working issue facing in m245p1 on some server thanks @Seep.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, also Magento 2.4.1 with PHP 7.4

$block->getCollection()->getSize()
in vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar.phtml

returns always 0 -> but products are shown in listing and are enabled and in stock.

reindexed, cache flushed - no luck

Anyone? Thanks

Comment: I changed my hosting plan from managed to unmanaged and installed Ubuntu with LAMP stack now the store is working perfectly.